# Simulate iOS 4 folder animation in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm trying to simulate the iOS4 folder appearance in Android. I have a Button in my layout, and when pressed I would like to `expand` a View with some other buttons or images and the rest of the screen pushed down.

Here's an example video showing how the iOS 4 folders works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6ZwC8TGwXo (0:44)

Is there any library or sample code on anything similar to this? Or maybe some indications on how to achieve this?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that looks really similar to the iOS folders animation. It's a custom Animation, here are the details: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/expanding-listview-items/